# How do you solve this right hand derivative

Tags: derivatives

[image: The Derivative]

The right hand derivative of the greatest integer function at zero is zero. This makes sense since the slope would have to be zero but when I try to solve it through the right hand derivative definition I get indefinite form(0/0) as shown
[image: here.]

Comment: You should use latex formula instead of image for the math formula

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! This [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: "The right hand derivative of the greatest integer function at zero is zero" is not true, the function jumps from zero for x<=0 to 1 for x>0 so the right hand derivative does not exist.

Comment: As $x\to 0^+$, $[x]=0$

Comment: So I guess you have the same issue when you are asked to find the derivative in $0$ of the constant $0$ function, haven't you?

Comment: @trula The derivative at 0 does not exist. But I'm pretty sure the right hand derivative exists. I think you confused the greatest integer function with the least integer function.

Comment: Presumably the "greatest integer function" gives the largest integer less than or equal to $x$, and for $0 \le x \lt 1$ gives $0$

Comment: @trula The greatest integer function as in "the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$" , not "the integer immediately greater than or equal to $x$" function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you take the limit, calculate $([x]-0)/x$, which is $0/x=0$ because you haven't reached $x=0$ yet.
Now find the limit of $0$, as $x\to 0^+$

Comment: Maybe I took an other function. If greatest integer means what henry says, you have a right hand derivative. For me greatest integer meant for 0<x<=1 f(x)=1 then you don't have one.

Comment: When I put 'greatest integer' into Google, it says what Henry says

Comment: Then the right derivative exists

Comment: Oh yea, I forget simple stuff sometimes. Thanks alot!

Comment: @trula What you describe is the least integer function(least integer greater than or equal to x). Greatest integer function means the greatest integer less than or equal to the number.

Comment: Thanks for the correction